# How to give video frame rate when appending to mp4 file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple time lapse desktop video recorder which you can use to append to the same file over multiple sessions, and the following code works, however it requires encoding with ffmpeg to set an fps that isn't a default 25. I want to avoid using cv2 so i'm going the long way around this problem.

So what would be a way to write the video to include an fps setting of some sort, without having to re-encode with ffmpeg.

```
import fpstimer
from typing import BinaryIO
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

timer = fpstimer.FPSTimer(0.2)

def video(chunk: bytes, file_handler: BinaryIO):
    file_handler.write(chunk)


while True:
    try:
        frame = ImageGrab.grab().convert('RGB')
        buf = BytesIO()
        frame.save(buf, format='PNG')
        byte_im = buf.getvalue()
        with open('output.mp4', "ab") as fh:
            video(byte_im, fh)
        timer.sleep()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('done')
        raise
```

Comment: That's not going to work.  An MP4 file is way more than a concatenated series of frames.  MP4 files have a tightly defined structure of headers and values.  What is your issue with OpenCV?

Comment: @TimRoberts maybe i haven't done enough research with OpenCV but from my understand to record I would need to get the frames first, and to append to a file I must first read it and then add the frames to the end. Would this not start to use up memory for larger files?